# wait.free() is freeing multiple agents instead of 1

Tags: anylogic

I currently have an `event` that is checked every 30 minutes and calls the `function`, which is used to check if conditions are met to free an agent `Patient`that is in `wait1`

The `event` uses the code below and theoretically causes all of the agents in the `wait1` to be checked.:

```
if (wait1.size() > 0){
    for (int i = 0; i < wait1.size(); i++)
        function(wait1.get(i));}
```

The `function` is seen below:

[image]

[image]

The problem is that although `patient` should theoretically only go from the `wait1` block to the `selectOutput3`and eventually a `seize` if they satisfy one of the conditions in the `function`, it happens that if multiple `patient` satisfy the same condition, they both get free'd. However, there is only 1 `SurgeonMorning` and 1 `SurgeonAfternoon`, so once a `patient` is freed from the `wait`, it should seize the surgeon and not allow any of the other `patients` to be freed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this happens because of the order of things happen

Anylogic first does the loop through all the agents in your wait block, and during the loop, the surgeon hasn't been seized yet so idle is always equal to true for all the agents in the wait block

you could so something like this

```
if (wait1.size() > 0){
    for (int i = 0; i < wait1.size(); i++){
        if(surgeonMorning.isReserved==false){
           surgeonMorning.isReserved=true;
           function(wait1.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

then on the release, you can do `surgeonMorning.isReserved=false` when the time comes.

Nevertheless, your whole model could just be replaced by 1 service block from what I see. You are overdoing the amount of code needed.

Comment: but shouldn't the surgeon be seized once one of the conditions are satisfied? And therefore isIdle() be set to false, not allowing any of the other conditions to come true as they depend on the surgeon being idle?

Comment: no... since the surgeon is not seized on the wait block, but later

Comment: so technically there is a very minimal amount of time between being freed from the wait and getting to the seize?

Comment: there is 0 time, but the order in which things happen are the opposite of what you would want

Comment: i have edited the question for clarity

Comment: as i said, instead of these 6 blocks, you should only use 1 service block... second, you can't seize a resource before the loop finished in the wait block... i already gave you a solution to add a reserved variable